# Where to place .Xresources on modern systems?

Tags: debian, x11, x-resources, motif

According to some old documentation about `mwm`, many settings for this window manager must be placed in an `.Xresources` folder in the $HOME directory.

When I normally boot up my computer (Debian 11), `mwm` appears to ignore and not load the settings in `~./Xresources`. I found a word around is to type `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`, but I'd like a permanent setting. What is the proper way to configure `mwm` on modern systems where `~/.Xresources` is no longer used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Debian 11 (using KDE, not `mwm` though), if the keyword `allow-user-resources` is present in `/etc/X11/Xsession.options`, and `~/.Xresources` exists in the user's home directory, then the session startup component script `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources` will use `xrdb -merge` to read it.

The user resource file location is defined by variable `USRRESOURCES`, which is defined in the main global X session script `/etc/X11/Xsession`.

If you are using `startx` and are providing your own `~/.startxrc` or `~/.xinitrc`, then the entire system-wide X11 session setup is overridden by your own session script. Then you are fully responsible for running your own `xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xresources` or equivalent. You might want to read `man startx` and `man 5 Xsession`, and pay attention to notes about Debian-specific customizations.

For example, in `man startx`:

> Note that in the Debian system, what many people traditionally put in the .xinitrc file should go in .xsession instead; this permits the same X environment to be presented whether startx, xdm, or xinit is used to start the X session. All discussion of the .xinitrc file in the xinit(1) manual page applies equally well to .xsession. Keep in mind that .xinitrc is used only by xinit(1) and completely ignored by xdm(1).

So if you are using `~/.xinitrc`, by using `~/.xsession` instead you might be able to avoid writing some boilerplate session setup actions, as they would be already provided by the system-wide defaults. Of course, if you are used to the hardcore old-school way of X11 session setup, and want your environment *just so*, then your current method might be a good fit for you.